# Bootstrap grid, padding issue causing background to overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Situation**

Using Boostrap v4, and when I add a background colour to a `div`, the element appears to become unaligned with all other elements in their columns. I have applied `box-sizing: border-box` yet it isn't staying within its container. Never had this issue before.

**Aim**

To keep the element within its column

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="container padding-bottom--md">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 bg--orange text-md-center padding-bottom--md padding-top--md">
            <h5 class="text-uppercase txt--white">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
            <p class="txt--white no-margin-bottom">A load of pish posh text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 bg--orange text-md-center padding-bottom--md padding-top--md">
            <h5 class="text-uppercase txt--white">Lorem Ipsum</h5>
            <p class="txt--white no-margin-bottom">A load of pish posh text</p>
        </div>
    </div>                          
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }


.padding-top--sm { padding-top: 1rem; }
.padding-bottom--sm { padding-bottom: 1rem; }
```

Comment: show your problem fiddle or codepen link. We can't figure out your problem exactly. is it look like this:    
[link] (http://codepen.io/inewton/pen/GjLjzj) . @Patric

Comment: @AmitKumar I have solved this issue but I will add a link to codepen in a minute

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve the issue. Add a second inner `div` to hold the content without any padding.

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 bg--white text-md-center padding-top--md">
                <div class="bg--orange padding-info-inner-md">
                    <h5 class="text-uppercase txt--white">Resource centre</h5>
                    <p class="txt--white no-margin-bottom">Got a question? Have you checked our knowledge bank and help guides?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.bg--orange { background: #e64b3c; }
.bg--white { background: #FFFFFF }
.padding-info-inner-md { padding: 2rem; }
```